# What’s our “elevator pitch”?

Tags: discussion

#5 from [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we're making a site that will be a repository for answers to real problems that network engineers encounter in their day to day working environment.  The great thing about it is that anyone can ask a question and answer, and the community can vote on which questions and answers are the most useful!

Comment: ¿ "Network Engineering is a repo..." ?

Answer (score 0):

When network engineer's want to discuss the finer point's of networking, they go to Network Engineering, where expert's vote on which Question's and Answer's they find best.