# Choosing a tagline and a motto

Tags: discussion

Similar to the [elevator pitch](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/231) - what would you suggest as a tagline or motto?

Taglines can be a short and clever sentence to the point, an even shorter motto could be a good companion to a logo.

Who has several ideas, could still put them into one post, the favorite first, to avoid a lot of two-word-posts. Readers still can comment if they upvote because of the 2nd or 3rd, or upvote such a comment. Im sure we will understand what's liked.

Comment: Where exactly does this show?  Is it where I see "Q&A for Network Engineers" currently?

Comment: Just found the answer to my comment:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/

Answer (score 1):

Tag lines:

- **Network engineering.** Building the backbone of the Internet.
- **Network engineering.** The tech behind speed and bandwidth.

Mottos, logo add-ons:

- Bandwidth matters.
- Throughput counts.

Answer (score 0):

Tag lines:

- Network Engineering. Building Better Networks.
- Network Engineering. Improving connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

**Network Engineering: *Picking up the Packets*.**
The packet picker uppers.

**Network Engineering: *Routing Questions to Answers*.**
Question-rcv-route-queued-xmt-Answered

j/k on this last one:
**Network Engineering: *The glue that no one smells*.**

Answer (score 0):

- **Network Engineering:** ***Routing around problems***
- **Network Engineering:** ***Internet? BTDT.***
- **Network Engineering:** ***You boot it, we route it.***

Motto:

- Our packets travel around the globe to connect the world.